# php fatal error intentando conectar base de datos a proyecto android studio

Tags: php, java, mysql, android

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es conectar una base de datos MySql a unos editText en android studio, para registrar los datos de usuario. Tengo un par de documentos .php que he añadido a los hotdocs de xampp (Login y Registro) si los busco en el browser me sale:

`Fatal error: Assignments can only happen to writable values in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro.php on line 12`

la linea 12 es `$response = array();` en el archivo .php (con password ocultada con x, son cinco integer):

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxxx", "janezazu");
   
   $mail = $_POST["mail"];
   $username = $_POST["username"];
   $password = $_POST["password"];
   $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (mail, username, password) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $mail, $username, $password);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
                
   $response = array();
   $response = ["success"] = true;
   
   echo json_encode($response);
   
   ?>
```

y

`Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php(2): mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'janezazu') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 2`

para la linea 2 de Login (donde janezazu es el nombre del bd), que es:

`$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxxx", "janezazu");`

en el archivo "Login.php":

```
<?php 
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxxx", "janezazu");
   
   $username = $_POST["username"];
   $password = $_POST["password"];
   
   $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
                
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $mail, $username, $password);
                
   $response = array();
   $response["success"] = false;
   
   while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
           $response["success"] = true;
           $response["mail"] = $mail;
           $response["username"] = $username;
           $response["password"] = $password;
           
           }
   
   echo json_encode($response);
   
?>
```

en realidad lo tengo casi todo hecho, no consigo resolver este problema.
Alguien que sepa algo sobre como evitar al error?

Answer (score 0):

El primer error ocurre aquí realmente:

```
$response = ["success"] = true;
```

Y es que eso no tiene sentido, lo que estás diciendo es que `$response` es igual a `["success"]` y es igual a `true` ¿?

La asignación correcta es:

```
$response ["success"] = true;
```

O, puedes declarar el array ya inicializado:

```
$response = array("success" => true);
```

PERO, no conviene hacer esto para tu caso, ya veremos por qué.

El segundo error es bastante claro:

> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

O el nombre de usuario, o el password o la base de datos no son correctos en ese contexto. Verifica por tanto y usas las credenciales correctas para conectar a la base de datos. Si todo es correcto, ese error podría ocurrir porque la base de datos está en otro puerto que no es el puerto por defecto `3306`, en cuyo caso deberás pasar el puerto correcto como quinto parámetro, [revisa el Manual de PHP al respecto](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php).

Dicho eso, vamos a mejorar tu código. Dado que es una respuesta que espera ser consumida por un cliente, controlaremos el flujo, poniendo siempre un array con dos claves: una será `status`, que será `true` o `false` según haya habido éxito o error y otra clave `msg` con un mensaje descriptivo de lo ocurrido que podrás usar para informar al cliente.

Algo MUY IMPORTANTE en estos casos es controlar todas las situaciones eventuales. En tu código hay vacíos en ese sentido, hay cosas que no verificas.

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxxx", "janezazu");
   if ( $con ) {
       $mail = $_POST["mail"] ?? null;
       $username = $_POST["username"] ?? null;
       $password = $_POST["password"] ?? null;
       if ( $mail && $username && $password ) {
           $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $con, "INSERT INTO user (mail, username, password) VALUES (?,?,?)" );
           if ( $stmt ) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "siss", $mail, $username, $password);
                if ( mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ) {
                    $response = array (
                                        'status'=>true,
                                        'msg'=>sprintf('Filas insertadas: %d',mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt))
                                       );
                } else {
                    $response = array (
                                        'status'=>false,
                                        'msg'=>'Error ejecutando la consulta'
                                       );
                }
            } else {
                $response = array (
                                    'status'=>false,
                                    'msg'=>'Error preparando la consulta'
                                   );
            }

        } else {
            $response = array (
                                'status'=>false,
                                'msg'=>'Datos a insertar incompletos'
                               );
        }
    } else {
        $response = array (
                            'status'=>false,
                            'msg'=>'No hay conexión'
                          );
    }
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

En el cliente, podrás hacer una verificación del tipo:

```
if(elObjetoDeLaRespuesta.getBoolean("status")) {
    //Hubo éxito, actuar en consecuencia y/o mostrar msg
} else {
    //Hubo error, actuar en consecuencia y/o mostrar msg
}
```

No me digas: *es un código más largo que el original*. Sí lo es, pero es un código maduro, que prevé control de posibles errores. Mientras un programa no prevea los errores, no es un programa maduro.

Comment: @MatteoCongiu la intención ha sido ayudar, no menospreciar a nadie en ningún momento ni decirte lo que debes o no debes hacer. Más bien caes en lo que supuestamente me atribuyes a mi, mandándome a dar una ducha ¿?  Me doy la ducha cuando quiera y como quiera, lo tuyo sí que es una falta de respeto y de consideración, así que he reportado tu comentario por irrespetuoso. Lo cierto es que un programa que no contemple manejo de errores nunca estará terminado. Si te tomas a mal las críticas, no avanzarás en la vida.

Comment: @Cedano el problema no son las criticas, sigue sin entender su error, el problema es el lenguaje y la manera de decir las cosas, 2 duchas frías.

Ah, por cierto, nada de lo que ha escrito ha funcionado, mismísimos errores, así que bajar la crestita y seguir estudiando.

Comment: @MatteoCongiu no veo en qué parte de la respuesta he mostrado altivez o desprecio. Quizá lo hayas interpretado así. Sea como sea, ya te he dicho que la intención ha sido ayudar. Todo lo demás son interpretaciones gratuitas. Si no aceptas la ayuda de esta manera o si no te sirve, pues a seguir estudiando y espero que lo puedas resolver. Saludos.

Comment: @MatteoCongiu si algo no funciona, por favor, aclaraselo al autor para que pueda revisar su respuesta. Esta respuesta no tiene ningun problema (podrias haberla reportado de ser asi)...

Comment: @Cedano Ya, ya veo que no entiendes, ya he dicho que el poblema no es la intención, no hay peor sordo del que no quiere escuchar y no saré yo el que te puede educar si no lo han hecho hasta ahora.

Comment: @MatteoCongiu ¿cuál es el problema exactamente en la respuesta dada? Realmente no entiendo tu postura y en cuanto a tu comentario último, que raya en la ofensa, debo decir que me considero una persona que ha sido educada correctamente y te lo digo no tanto por mi, sino por aquellos me han educado, muchos de ellos ya fallecidos. Evita pues la ofensas personales.